# Promise.all recursive

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

I have the following program (it should be executable as such) in which I have problems to handle a recursive call to a method that involves many asynchronous operations.

As a starting point in the program I have a `test()` method. It triggers the first call to `_add()` to which it passes the `root` object (a tree of nested "elements").

The `_add` method is responsible for adding the nested elements into the `storage` (which I have represented here by a simple array). In order to do so, I have written the function so that it calls itself on all the children elements.

Storing an element is an asynchronous operation. Hence, I am using an array of promises to hold the "not yet available" value of all children elements.

As show by `test()`, I do not manage to properly handle the synchronization here. All elements should have been inserted in the storage before the promise returned by the first call to `add()` resolves. This it apparently not the case as the output of the program shows.

Of course, since the parentId of a child refers to the id of its parent, it's important for me that the storage operation happens in the same order at which the tree of elements is explored.

I am anticipating to have the exact same kind of problem when trying to retrieve elements from the `storage`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
(() => {
  const storage = [];
  const root = {
    _type: "root",
    title: "root element",
    gravity: null,
    children: [
      {
        _type: "space",
        title: "my first space",
        gravity: 0,
        children: [
          {
            _type: "bundle",
            title: null,
            gravity: 0,
            children: [
              {
                _type: "vis",
                title: "my first vis",
                gravity: 0,
                visualization: {
                  url: "http://dummyvis.com/#8766"
                },
                children: null
              },
              {
                _type: "feature",
                title: "my feature 1",
                gravity: 1,
                feature: {
                  componentType: "CPT_FEATURE1"
                },
                children: []
              },
              {
                _type: "feature",
                title: "my feature 2",
                gravity: 1,
                feature: {
                  componentType: "CPT_FEATURE2"
                },
                children: []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  const store = (element, parentId) => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

      storage.push({id:element.id, _type:element._type, gravity: element.gravity, parent:parentId, created_date:Date.now() });

      setTimeout( () => resolve(element), 500);
    });
  }

  const _add = (element, recurse, parentId) => {
    console.log(element._type);
    if(!element._type) 
      throw new Error("an element must declare a key '_type'");
    parentId = parentId || null;

    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      const promises = [];

      promises.push( new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        store(element, parentId)
          .then(element => {
            resolve(element);
          })
          .catch(err => reject(err));
      }));

      Promise.all(promises)
        .then( res => {
          if(recurse && element.children.length > 0) {
            element.children.forEach( child => {
              _add(child, recurse, element.id);
            });
          }
          resolve(element);
        })
        .catch( err => reject(err));
    });
  }

  const test = () => {
    _add(root, true)
      .then( res => {
        console.log("----------------------------------------------------------");
        console.log("Test completed. Nothing should be printed after this line!");
        console.log("------------------------------------------------------...-");
      })
      .catch( err => {

      });
  }
  test();
})();
```

output:

```
decisionspace
----------------------------------------------------------
Test completed. Nothing should be printed after this line!
------------------------------------------------------...-
bundle
visualization
feature
feature
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
  Promise.all(promises)
    .then( res => {
      if(recurse && element.children.length > 0) {
        element.children.forEach( child => {
          _add(child, recurse, element.id);
        });
      }
      resolve(element);
    })
```

`_add()` returns a promise immediately and will complete its task later, asynchronously. When the `forEach` loop is done, the `_add()`s have not yet completed their task.

If you want to ensure that elements are added in order, waiting that the previous `_add()` has completed is task before invoking the next one, you can write:

```
  Promise.all(promises)
    .then( res => {
      var taskQueue = Promise.resolve();
      if(recurse && element.children.length > 0) {
        element.children.forEach( child => {
          taskQueue = taskQueue.then(() => _add(child, recurse, element.id));
        });
      }
      taskQueue.then(() => resolve(element));
    })
```

If you don't care if the elements are not added in order, you can write:

```
  Promise.all(promises)
    .then( res => {
      var tasks = [];
      if(recurse && element.children.length > 0) {
        element.children.forEach( child => {
          tasks.push(_add(child, recurse, element.id));
        });
      }
      Promise.all(tasks).then(() => resolve(element));
    })
```